# Server response time high when InnoDB tables active but not being accessed

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am experiencing high server response time (up to 5 seconds) when loading every Webpage on my server, ONLY when MySQL InnoDB tables are running.

The 5 second delay occurs even on static HTML pages with no call to any MySQL data table (and no other users on the site accessing other InnoDB linked webpages).

As soon as the InnoDB is shutdown (MyISAM tables remain active), all pages (those that call DB or not) load very fast (including MyISAM tables) in about a second.

How could InnoDB be causing server wide slow response, even when not being accessed?

Comment: Does not make sense.  Let's see some more details.

Comment: MySQL and an http daemon on the same server... sounds like a potential recipe for swapfile thrashing.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I enabled query_cache_type=1 and query_cache_size=256M.

The problem went away and the server response reduced from 6 seconds to 1 second. Very strange considering most recommend that Query cache should be disabled!